# Internal server error 500 retrofit even after every parameter is correct

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to get json object from REST Api. But I am getting internal server error. 
The response is coming in postman.

```
BankAccount bankAccount = APIClient.getApiClient().create(BankAccount.class);
        Call<JsonElement> call = bankAccount.getBusinessDetails("JWT "+ user_token, business_id);
        Log.d("data", "JWT "+ user_token +" id "+  business_id);
        Log.d("URLCalled", call.request().url().toString());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonElement> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(BusinessProfile.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(BusinessProfile.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("error", response.raw().toString() + response.headers().toString() + response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface BankAccount {

    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })



    @GET("buisnesses/{business_id}")
    Call<JsonElement> getBusinessDetails(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                      @Path("business_id") String business_id);


}
```

After trying so many response types like ResponseBosy, JsonObject etc. still it didn't work.

dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
```

Comment: 500 - server error has nothing to do with the client, contact the back-end.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher please check my edited question

Comment: Post the output of this line `Log.d("error", response.raw().toString() + response.headers().toString() + response.message());`

Comment: @Ranjan D/error: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=
    Internal Server Error

Comment: Welp! That doesn't help much. 500 error is when you are sending something that backend isn't expecting. If you have access to the server logs, you can see what exactly is wrong. Or you can try logging your request in Android studio which might reveal some useful info https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses.

Comment: Check your backend code. Error is in there. Try using `Postman`, Yo will get same result.

Comment: *500 error is when you are sending something that backend isn't expecting* - that is so not true

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher to be fair, a HTTP code of 500 **CAN** (keyword here is can!!!!!) also mean the client just 100% send the request incorrectly which caused the request to fail server sided leading to an internal error.

Comment: to be fair, if the client sends an incorrect request, the server should handle it. 500 errors are never the fault of the client

Comment: well ok :P this is another debate. still issue is unsolved :P